# Routing on-premise BeyondTrust to Azure cloud

Tags: azure, networking, privileges, on-premises-instances, user-access-manager

BeyondTrust is being used on-premise. How would I configure the network so that the cloud is also a target for BeyondTrust i.e. route traffic from beyondtrust onprem to targets in Azure cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your on-premise to Azure by setting up an Azure S2S VPN from your on-premise. [Here are more details on setting up the same.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal)

Further, you can also setup an Azure Express Route Circuit. ExpressRoute circuits connect your on-premises infrastructure to Microsoft through a connectivity provider. [Here are more details on setting up the same.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-circuit-peerings)

Hope this helps. If you need any further assistance, please do let us know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a question of routing. If you have an open route to the targets, Password Safe will be able to reach them.